# Newbie completely stuck with texture issue

Tags: texturing

On my first week of learning Blender and I am drawing a complete blank trying to solve this texture issue. I'm also not exactly sure what the problem is, so searching for a solution has proved impossible. I think I'm just missing something fundamental here.

This is my object, essentially nothing more than a cube with rounded edges
[image]

Wireframe view of the same
[image]

This is how it gets rendered
[image]

The texture starts over for every vertex that make up the object. All I want is the object to look like it does in the "Solid" view -  one smooth piece with the texture applied in one piece.

What am I doing wrong? I thought I finally found a solution elsewhere where someone suggested marking the edges sharp and then apply an edge split modifier, but that made no difference.

Would appreciate any help enormously! Thanks

Comment: Suggest you read up and watch a few videos on UV unwrapping objects before going any further!

Comment: I agree with John.If you just share the file link I can teach you how to unwrap your mesh.

Comment: A few videos on UV unwrapping later and I managed to produce something that looks like I wanted it to. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys! I was about to pull my hair out.

Comment: Maybe close the question or mark as answered? If I knew it was solve I wouldn't have unnecessarily clicked on it.